# Exception in thread and stack trace shows call to _endthreadex

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, exception, stack-trace

I am currently debugging a crash in one of my applications and stumbled up on something that looks a bit odd to me.
In my application I start several threads using _beginthreadex function. At some random point in time (sometimes after several hours) one of the threads crashes for a yet unknown reason. The stack trace at the time of the crash looks like this:

```
my.dll!thread(void * p=0x241e0140)  Line 792 + 0xf bytes    C
msvcr90.dll!__endthreadex()  + 0x44 bytes   
msvcr90.dll!__endthreadex()  + 0xd8 bytes   
kernel32.dll!_BaseThreadStart@8()  + 0x37 bytes
```

where thread is the main loop function of my thread. I omitted the stack frames above my thread function here. The crash is an access violation and happens each time at the same location with the exact same bad pointer value.

Now what made me think is that __endthreadex occurs in the stack trace. I tried to reproduce this in a small sample program and caused an access violation there too. However the stack trace looks different:

```
test.exe!thread(void * vpb=0x00000000)  Line 9 + 0x3 bytes  C++
test.exe!_callthreadstartex()  Line 348 + 0x6 bytes C
test.exe!_threadstartex(void * ptd=0x000328e8)  Line 326 + 0x5 bytes    C
kernel32.dll!_BaseThreadStart@8()  + 0x37 bytes
```

The corresponding code is this:

```
static unsigned __stdcall thread( void * vpb )
{
    int *a = (int*)0xdeadbeef;
    *a = 0;

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE th = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, thread, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL );

    for(int i=0; i<INT_MAX;)
    {
        ++i;
    }

    ResumeThread(th);

    for(int i=0; i<INT_MAX;)
    {
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The original code looks similar to this but is obviously more complex. So I'm no wondering if the differences in the stack trace might be caused by my modifications to the code when implementing the small example or if all this shows that there is a problem with a corrupted stack.

So my question is basically: Is it possible that _BaseThreadStart calls __endthreadex which again calls the thread function itself? And if so, can someone explain why this is the case because to me it looks odd and I'm thinking if this points out some problem which might be related to my initial problem of the crashing thread.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.